# PHP array to jQuery options

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating a Wordpress Plugin which uses a jQuery script. I've created a PHP array which contains its options like:

`$settings = array('setting1' => 'value1', 'setting2' => 'value2', 'setting3' => 10)`

I was now going to use foreach to loop over the items and print them like this:

```
foreach($settings as $setting => $value) {

if (is_string($value)) { $value = "'" . $value . "'"; }
$output .= $setting . ':' . $value .',';
```

}

which should make me end up with:

```
(window).load(function() {
$('#widget').myWidget({
    setting1:'value1', 
    setting2:'value2', 
    setting3:10})
```

With the current setup I end up with the last entry having a ',' at the end (one too many) which means I get a Javascript error, so I need to remove it.

All with all, I have the feeling I'm doing something very dirty (including the is_string check) and I was wondering if there is a neat way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function if you're using PHP >= 5.2

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for this. It does all the dirty work for you.

```
(window).load(function() {
    $('#widget').myWidget(
        <?php echo json_encode($settings); ?>
    );
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I never imagined it would be so easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, the JSON support is really nice.. And btw., it works in both directions (`json_decode()`) :).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php) ?

Exemple from the docs:

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Would output

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little thing I like to use when dealing with situations like this. I know it doesn't really answer your question, but it is an elegant way of solving the comma problem.

```
$comma = '';
foreach($settings as $setting => $value) {
  if (is_string($value)) { 
    $value = "'" . $value . "'";
    $output .= $comma . $setting . ':' . $value;
    $comma = ',';
  }
}
```

So on the first run $comma is blank, but after that it gets put between every new entry.

Comment: No -1 because this solution works, but definitely not a good one.

Comment: Could you enlighten me as to why this is not a good solution. Perhaps my code is suffering for it...

Comment: Because an existing function, json_encode, already do the work. Odds are that this function will be maintained longer that your personnal code and by smarter people that you and me.